# Howto count in Excel based on string beginning

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Assume the following Excel worksheet:

```
  A                                B            C
1 Item                         In progress  Completed
2 FOO|01|442532342|fdsfdsfsd4     15            5
3 BAR|05|534527777|gfdsfdsfsd     10            5
4 BAR|9633|fdfssdfdsfdsf|5444     20           10
5 BAR|4543|fgfddsfds|34324325      5            0
6 FOO|efdfs|fdsfs|42321321323      5            5
7 BAZ|eree|34533432432|gfffdd     30           20
8 FOOBAR|fdfsdfs|432432|gdfgf     35            5
9 FOOBAR|sdfs534324324|43|223      0            0
```

(1) I would like to scan the `A` column and identify unique Items based on the text before the first pipe (`|`). In this case this would be:

```
FOO
BAR
BAZ
FOOBAR
```

This lookup should be dynamic, so if a tenth Item would be `BARBAZ|sdadadsd|34343324322`, then the return should be:

```
FOO
BAR
BAZ
FOOBAR
BARBAZ
```

(2) I need to tally the `B` and `C` columns for each Item type. So the total output for the original example would be (calculations within brackets for clarity)

```
FOO     20 (15+5)      10 (5+5)
BAR     35 (10+20+5)   15 (5+10+0)
BAZ     30 (30)        20 (20)
FOOBAR  35 (35+0)       5 (5+0)
```

The `B` and `C` colums are hardcoded sort to speak: there will not be a `D` column with additional values and if there will be, I can update te formula manually. The thing is I'm having a hard time getting started with this. Can it be done with a formula or is there a need for VBA?

After @KazJaws comment, I decided to try and write VBA. I now have this but I need expanding. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Sub CreateStats()
    Dim itemSplit
    Dim item
    itemSplit = Split(Columns(0).Value, "|")
    item = itemSplit(1)
End Sub
```

It generates an error, though: "Can't Execute Code in Break Mode"

Comment: there are few possibilities to get what you need... **without VBA** - use `text-to-column` for your A column, than you could use either `pivot table` or `SumIf function` to get B & C summary. **with VBA**- use loops + Dictionary + some functions (like Split)...

Answer (score 1):

Use text to columns to split column A by the "|" then [use an extract distinct list from a list formula that can be found here.](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/)

Then use a `SUMIFS()` formula where it's sum range is the In Progress column, it's criteria range is the Item Column, and the criteria is the first item in the distinct list you created.
Then just add another column for the Completed values.

```
Cell H3 =INDEX($B$3:$B$10,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$B$3:$B$10),0,0),0))`
Cell I3 =SUMIFS($F$3:$F$10,$B$3:$B$10,H3)
Cell J3 =SUMIFS($G$3:$G$10,$B$3:$B$10,H3)
```

Should look like this,
[image]

Comment: Thanks - this is a great solution, but still requires quite some manual work. Could you help me progress with a VBA solution a little?

Comment: Sure, let's start with how do you get the file/info that you displayed? I will try to find some time to makea VBA solution.